# Read multi-level json in python with pandas from url

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I try to read multi-level JSON with pandas and store data in the data-frame for next work with it or for print. The main goal for me is to understand how to read data from each level of JSON.

Here you are my first steps, which works:

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests
log = ("user", "password")
url = "http://serverxyz/api/v1/Catalog/Categories?pageSize=2&pageIndex=0"

req = requests.get(url, auth = log)
req.raise_for_status()
d = req.json()

#what is next step?
#something like this? df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d.Data)
```

Could you tell me, how to read:

- 1st level (columns PageIndex, PageSize, TotalCount, Data)
- 2 level (from Data columns Code, Timestamp, Category, snapshots)
- 3 level (from Data and snapshots columns Code, DateFrom, DateTo, Type ...)
- some good tip for next work with data?
- maybe you tell me, that using pandas is not the best way how to read JSON

Here is json:

[my json file to download from OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aq_13Yi67kkxal9mwhaPvPj2udM)

```
{"PageIndex":0,"PageSize":2,"TotalCount":100248,"Data":[{"Code":"859182400102974","Timestamp":"2019-04-17T12:16:51Z","Category":0,"snapshots":[{"Code":"859182400102974","DateFrom":"2016-12-31T23:00:00Z","DateTo":"2017-05-09T22:00:00Z","Type":"CCO","VoltageLevel":400,"IsIsland":false,"IsPps":false,"MeasurementType":"CMC","InstalledPower":0,"GridId":11,"MeteredDataProvider":"8591824048108","Supplier":"8591824071403","SubjectOfSettlement":"8591824071403","IsSummarizingForSubjectOfSettlement":false,"AnnualConsumptionEstimation":-502,"TDDClass":"004","TempArea":"009","IsForeign":false,"IsSLRActive":false,"DGIFrequency":1,"FirstMonthReading":5,"IsCompositeService":true,"IsAggregatedInvoice":true,"IsImplicitSoS":false,"ReservedPower":0,"PhasesCount":"3","IsMicrosource":false,"IsDisconnectionPlanned":false,"Name":"Petra"},{"Code":"859182400102974","DateFrom":"2017-05-09T22:00:00Z","DateTo":"2018-01-31T23:00:00Z","Type":"CCO","VoltageLevel":400,"IsIsland":false,"IsPps":false,"MeasurementType":"CMC","InstalledPower":0,"GridId":11,"MeteredDataProvider":"8591824048108","Supplier":"8591824071403","SubjectOfSettlement":"8591824071403","IsSummarizingForSubjectOfSettlement":false,"AnnualConsumptionEstimation":-382,"TDDClass":"004","TempArea":"009","IsForeign":false,"IsSLRActive":false,"DGIFrequency":1,"FirstMonthReading":5,"IsCompositeService":true,"IsAggregatedInvoice":true,"IsImplicitSoS":false,"ReservedPower":0,"PhasesCount":"3","IsMicrosource":false,"IsDisconnectionPlanned":false,"Name":"Petra"}],"scalars":{"ConsumptionEstimation":[{"DateFrom":"2016-12-31T23:00:00Z","DateTo":"2017-05-09T22:00:00Z","ConsumptionEstimation":-502},{"DateFrom":"2017-05-09T22:00:00Z","DateTo":"2018-01-31T23:00:00Z","ConsumptionEstimation":-382}],"ConsumptionEstimation2":[{"DateFrom":"2016-12-31T23:00:00Z","DateTo":"2017-05-09T22:00:00Z","ConsumptionEstimation2":-502},{"DateFrom":"2017-05-09T22:00:00Z","DateTo":"2018-01-31T23:00:00Z","ConsumptionEstimation2":-382}]}},{"Code":"859182400104897","Timestamp":"2019-04-17T12:16:51Z","Category":0,"snapshots":[{"Code":"859182400104897","DateFrom":"2016-11-18T23:00:00Z","DateTo":"2017-11-05T23:00:00Z","Type":"CCO","VoltageLevel":400,"IsIsland":false,"IsPps":false,"MeasurementType":"CMC","InstalledPower":0,"GridId":11,"MeteredDataProvider":"8591824048108","Supplier":"8591824071403","SubjectOfSettlement":"8591824071403","IsSummarizingForSubjectOfSettlement":false,"AnnualConsumptionEstimation":-280,"TDDClass":"004","TempArea":"009","IsForeign":false,"Address":{"Street":"Okružní","City":"Semovo Ústí","PostCode":"39102"},"IsSLRActive":false,"DGIFrequency":0,"FirstMonthReading":0,"IsCompositeService":false,"IsAggregatedInvoice":false,"IsImplicitSoS":false,"ReservedPower":0,"IsMicrosource":false,"IsDisconnectionPlanned":false,"Name":"Martin"},{"Code":"859182400104897","DateFrom":"2017-11-05T23:00:00Z","DateTo":"2027-01-16T23:00:00Z","Type":"CCO","VoltageLevel":400,"IsIsland":false,"IsPps":false,"MeasurementType":"CMC","InstalledPower":0,"GridId":11,"MeteredDataProvider":"8591824048108","Supplier":"8591824071403","SubjectOfSettlement":"8591824071403","IsSummarizingForSubjectOfSettlement":false,"AnnualConsumptionEstimation":-282,"TDDClass":"004","TempArea":"009","IsForeign":false,"Address":{"Street":"Okružní","City":"Semovo Ústí","PostCode":"39102"},"IsSLRActive":false,"DGIFrequency":0,"FirstMonthReading":0,"IsCompositeService":false,"IsAggregatedInvoice":false,"IsImplicitSoS":false,"ReservedPower":0,"IsMicrosource":false,"IsDisconnectionPlanned":false,"Name":"Martin"}],"scalars":{"ConsumptionEstimation":[{"DateFrom":"2016-11-18T23:00:00Z","DateTo":"2017-11-05T23:00:00Z","ConsumptionEstimation":-280},{"DateFrom":"2017-11-05T23:00:00Z","DateTo":"2027-01-16T23:00:00Z","ConsumptionEstimation":-282}],"ConsumptionEstimation2":[{"DateFrom":"2016-11-18T23:00:00Z","DateTo":"2017-11-05T23:00:00Z","ConsumptionEstimation2":-280},{"DateFrom":"2017-11-05T23:00:00Z","DateTo":"2027-01-16T23:00:00Z","ConsumptionEstimation2":-282}]}}]}
```

Thank you

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: tables. 1st table with columns PageIndex, PageSize, TotalCount, Data and theirs values. 2nd table with columns Code, Timestamp, Category, snapshots and their values. 3rd table with columns Code, DateFrom, DateTo, Type ... and their values ... maybe something more too but above it is base for me

Comment: You should mock up exactly the 3 table headers so we know how to map info. Why are you repeating info across tables also? data contains 2 dictionaries with nested content. Are you really planning on unraveling all of that in table 1 for example where you say _data_?

Answer (score 0):

I think using `pandas` to process JSON is not a good choice, because `pandas` is trying to deal with **structural data**, but in your example you are dealing with multi-level **unstructured data**.
But if you insist to do that, you can extract structural data from your JSON structure. For example, you can extract the `array` in `JSON_ROOT."Data"."snapshots"`  into an ArrayList and save it into `pd.DataFrame`. Otherwise, you can only save the JSON structure as a `string` in one column in `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: Thank you. I don't insist to use pandas, I thought that it is the best way for next work with data when I use pandas for read it. But I want to hear opinion of people with more experience. Could you tell me how to make it different with your procedure?

Comment: @palo173 I guess what you want to do is: 1. get data from api, 2. store data into DataFrame. I think you can separate the two steps and writing a `mapping function` to transfer your original API data into a `table` structure, (it can be store whatever in a list or a dict object). Then you can consider whether choosing SQL or pandas to do some statistic analysis.

Comment: And how to transfer API data into a table structure?

Comment: @palo173 use `json` package load the JSON string into a dict object, then parse the dict into the format you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

From answers above I am not more clever as before.

So I try to reduce my question to one question.
How Can I get table with 4 columns: 
Data.Code; Data.snapshots.DateFrom; Data.snapshots.Address.Street; Data.snapshots.Address.City

This is my code, but it is necessary to correct it, but I do not how. The Code works but it returns 30 columns and not exactly what I want.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import pandas.io.json as pd_json

log = ("user", "password")
url = "http://serverxyz/api/v1/Catalog/Categories?pageSize=2&pageIndex=0"

req = requests.get(url, auth = log)
req.raise_for_status()
fin = req.json()

df = pd_json.json_normalize(fin, 
                        record_path=['Data','snapshots'],
                        record_prefix = 'Data.',
                        errors = 'ignore'
                        )

print(df)
```

Thank you for help.